# Error Service Unavailable HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable

Tags: sharepoint, iis-7, active-directory

> I had SharePoint project and I setup the SharePoint on separated
>   server and SQL on separated server and AD on other server .
>
> when I go to change the **SPadmin** , **SPfarm** passwords . I had this error
>   when run the SharePoint central admin  "**Service Unavailable HTTP
>   Error 503. The service is unavailable**".
>
> when I checked the error I found that the Application Pool stopped ,
>   when I started it , it returned stopped again .
>
> **So How can I solve this issue ? .**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run following cmdlet:

```
Set-SPManagedAccount - UseExistingPassword -Identity DOMAIN\SPSAdmin
```

More info about [Set-SPManagedAccount](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607617.aspx)